# Is there an "addition theorem" of logarithm?

Tags: analysis, logarithms, closed-form

In trigonometry, there is a relation called the addition theorem:

$\begin{align} \sin(A+B) &= \sin{A}\cos{B}+\cos{A}\sin{B} \\ \cos{(A+B)} &= \cos{A}\cos{B} -\sin{A}\sin{B}\end{align}$

I wondered if there is a similar relation for logarithms. So what I want to know is that, **is there a polynomial or a rational function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies
$\log(a+b)= f(\log(a),\log(b))$?**(Assume $a>0,b>0$)

I think it is highly unlikely, but I haven't been able to prove that. I also would love to know if we can loosen the restriction on $f(x,y)$ and make it true.

Comment: [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation/subtraction) says something about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's the other way round:

$$\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$$

or

$$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b).$$

In fact, via the complex numbers, the first identity directly leads to the trigonometric ones.

---

We can refute the hypothesis $$\log(a+b)=f(\log(a)+\log(b))$$ for rational functions *with algebraic coefficients*.

Indeed,

$$\log(2)=\log(1+1)=f(\log(1),\log(1))=f(0,0)$$ is a transcendental number, but cannot be the result of a rational function with algebraic coefficients applied to algebraic arguments.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the definition of rational function, but isn’t a function like $f(x,y)=\pi$ a rational function? How is it that $f(0,0)$ cannot be a transcendental number?

Comment: @Kaira: you are right, I should have said with rational (or algebraic) coefficients.